# Hiding unfilled fields in pdf/html templates via source code

Tags: netsuite, pdfhtml

I'd like to make certain fields invisible/disappear when remain unfilled.

i.e. Email: 
This will result in the email text field not being printed out

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I do that.  It's a custom field, on mine, but the logic is the same.  The *?has_content* piece is what tests for data in the field.

```
<#if record.custbody_bill_to_email?has_content>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 147px;"><span style="font-size:10px;"><strong>Email</strong></span></td>
    <td style="width: 175px;"><span style="font-size:11px;">${record.custbody_bill_to_email}</span></td>
  </tr>
</#if>
```

Comment: I've used a combination of ?has_content and !="" or !=" " for this purpose, depending on the field. ?has_content won't work if your default value is 0 or N/A, for example.